# How to limit the width of a navbar using react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

so my navbar component is taking up the entire width of my page. That's fine but I would like to fix the content in my navbar to a relative width like 70vw. Just like here on stack overflow (when using a bigger screen at least) the content of the entire page is not taking up the entire width, leaving free space on the left and right side.


My component looks like this:

```
import logo from "../assets/images/logo.svg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const menuItems = {
    "Home": ["/"],
    "Editor": ["/editor-menu", "/editor-main"],
    "Premium⭐": ["/premium"]
};

const NavbarComp = () => {
    return (
        <Navbar bg="dark" expand="sm" variant="dark">
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
                <img
                    alt="FitSet logo"
                    src={logo}
                    width="30"
                    height="30"
                    className="d-inline-block align-top mr-2"
                />
                FitSet
            </Link>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    {Object.entries(menuItems).map(([key, value]) => (
                        <Link
                            key={key}
                            to={value[0]}
                            className={
                                (value.includes(window.location.pathname) &&
                                    "text-white") + " nav-link"
                            }
                        >
                            {key}
                        </Link>
                    ))}
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
};

export default NavbarComp;
```

I'm new to react and very eager to learn, so if any lines could be optimized or improved in some way, make sure to let me know.

Comment: You can create a new css file and import it in your component and override the `width` property.